# Startup JavaScript code is not executed when using the Firefox "Back" button

Tags: javascript, firefox, back

[This website](http://www.vanschneider.com/) has a fancy effect: when a navigation link is clicked, the content fades out and when the new page (on a different URL) loads, its contents fade in.

What's interesting is, after users click on the "Back" button of their browsers, they go back to the previous page and **the content still fades in**. In other words, the previous page doesn't stay at the faded-out state, which is what was last seen. According to [this comment](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?64497-Page-fade-in-code&s=e5a2ccbfcccc37aa40eaa6e301738118&p=260573#post260573), a page should be staying at its last seen state.

I tried many ways to reproduce this effect, yet on my tests, after clicking on the "Back" button the previous page still shows nothing (the content stays at the faded-out state). Sometimes it works on some browsers but not on others. Sometimes it works, but then it doesn't after reopening the browser.

How does the website implement this effect, which even works after users use the "Back" button to go to the previous page?

=== EDIT 1 ===

[Here are my test pages](https://googledrive.com/host/0BwkLXIVz0y59MWEtc04zTHo5bW8/page-1.html).

=== EDIT 2 ===

The above test pages have been tested with Firefox on three different PCs, and Firefox from version 4 all the way to version 20 via an online cross-browser testing service. And the results are the same: doesn't work.

Comment: not sure what your asking but you could use a js cookie to track "states".

Comment: @mpm, could you briefly illustrate how that is done?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**You need a very simple workaround:** hook into `window.unload` event, and a specific condition to reload the page inside `window.onpageshow`!

---

## **Firefox fix**

jQuery:

```js
$(window).unload(function () { $(window).unbind('unload'); });
```

JavaScript:

```js
function UnloadHandler() { window.removeEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false); }
window.addEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false);
```

## **iOS Safari fix**

jQuery:

```js
$(window).bind('pageshow', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
});
```

JavaScript:

```js
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
}, false);
```

## **Working sample**

Since I don't have access to update your page, I've [uploaded one here](http://misc.orangecoding.com/fadingpage.html).

---

**Why Firefox needs `window.onunload`?** [MDN window.unload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onunload) says:

> Using this event handler in your page prevents Firefox 1.5 from caching the page in the in-memory bfcache. See [Using Firefox 1.5 caching](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching) for details.

Some users *might* not want to disable Firefox's bfcache [see section *[Page caching despite unload and beforeunload handlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_Firefox_1.5_caching)*), and it is why the Firefox fix above is *unbinding the `onunload` event **inside** of the `onunload` event*.

**Why Safari needs `window.onpageshow`?** Apparently there's no way of disabling Safari's "*bfcache*", and we **must** refresh the page when it's shown.

**PS. *bfcache* means *back/forward cache*.**

---

Full HTML/JavaScript for reference:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
        <a href="fadingpage.html?p=1">Page 1</a>
        <a href="fadingpage.html?p=2">Page 2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas laoreet imperdiet diam, in sodales velit porta eget. Ut tellus urna, vestibulum vel facilisis eu, blandit sed est. Sed tortor justo, interdum vel iaculis eu, semper ut libero. Morbi porttitor sem eget dolor eleifend fermentum. Mauris lacinia dictum lacus ut pharetra. Proin lacus felis, vestibulum sit amet malesuada id, pretium at lorem. Duis elementum sapien vitae nibh consequat tincidunt. Proin gravida rhoncus metus sed feugiat. Sed ultricies tellus et augue adipiscing dictum. In vitae tellus eget sapien fringilla tincidunt. Vestibulum gravida, velit quis mattis elementum, lacus felis vestibulum neque, et commodo quam orci quis odio. Nunc varius viverra metus, eu dictum massa venenatis vel. Cras suscipit, orci a gravida pretium, erat massa facilisis turpis, quis sodales sem metus vitae ligula. Nunc interdum augue vel arcu vulputate quis aliquet nulla vehicula. Suspendisse eros odio, ultrices hendrerit euismod nec, condimentum sed metus.</p>
        <p>Donec at dolor et arcu aliquam tincidunt. Nulla eu elit sit amet leo facilisis posuere. Etiam non elit ac elit ornare elementum a vitae felis. Aenean semper nunc urna. Ut et interdum mi. Duis mollis est eu leo gravida vitae adipiscing leo commodo. Ut scelerisque cursus nulla, nec bibendum elit molestie sed. Nulla facilisi. Proin neque arcu, aliquam sed sagittis non, ultrices in enim. Fusce vitae nunc neque, ut sodales magna. Proin aliquam lobortis augue sed aliquet. Maecenas sit amet pellentesque mauris. Donec luctus purus hendrerit nisl pharetra eleifend. Mauris a lectus mi. In elit dui, porta a venenatis vel, consectetur id magna. Quisque vehicula leo vel nulla convallis quis sollicitudin sem fringilla.</p>
        <p>Morbi nec mi odio, eget porttitor nisi. Duis luctus blandit lacus. Donec quis sagittis mi. Maecenas id nisl enim. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nulla facilisi. Donec ac velit diam, interdum rutrum mauris. Nullam at odio eget felis tempus elementum. Nam a augue nibh, sed bibendum massa. Vivamus eget sollicitudin mauris. Pellentesque dapibus quam nec ligula blandit scelerisque. In vulputate mauris vel dolor interdum vitae aliquet nisl convallis. In massa mi, consectetur id malesuada at, suscipit vitae libero. Sed a ligula erat.</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('body').hide().fadeIn(800);
            $('a').click(function() {
                var href = $(this).attr('href');
                $('body').fadeOut(800, function() {
                    window.location = href;
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
        // Firefox fix
        $(window).unload(function () { $(window).unbind('unload'); });
        // iOS Safari fix
        $(window).bind('pageshow', function(event) {
            if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
                window.location.reload() 
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't act as if the cache was disabled completely. Firefox' **bfcache** is simply an *in-memory* cache that Firefox uses to be *faster* when going backwards/forwards in its history. Basically, bfcache stores a copy of the page in its last state in memory; by using the `onunload` event, it will **not** use bfcache, but the page is **still cached** in the cache repository.

Comment: @IanY. I've updated my answer explaining how to *re-enable* bfcache. Though, because I have no way (or know how) to test bfcache, I'm just taking Mozilla's word for it.

Comment: @Jesse THANK YOU for posting this solution, it worked perfectly! I was also having the jquery animation not work on Firefox when the back button was used. Your solution still works in 2020.

Answer (score 4):

For anybody running in problems with `Rails` and this -- your issue isn't bfcache -- it's the `turbolinks` gem. [Here](http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4) is how to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's not not exactly what you are asking, but they achive the effect in this way: page content starts hidden.
That's always, even when you click back button, because content hidden is declared in a style or class in markup.
Then there's javascript code that fadeIn the content after the ready event:

```
$('#content').fadeIn(800);
```

Comment: Yes, it uses that method to fade in content. But how could that be able to effect the previous page? Clicking on "back" button doesn't make the previous page executing any JavaScript code.

Comment: When you click back, code of the previous page is executed again.
"Back button" only doesn't reload html from the server, but it execute again javascript code.
So: -> click back -> reload html from cache: it starts "hidden" -> exec fadeIn()

Comment: I had set up test pages. Could you check them?

Comment: I'm seeing it working as I suppose it should, in Firefox. Not working in Chrome and IE because browsers are blocking jquery.min.js script for security reason (you are running unders https and script in under http).
Use: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: I just changed the jQuery url to https. It works on some places, but not on others. When I use [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/) to test Firefox, it doesn't work. And it doesn't work on the Firefox on my PC, neither.

Comment: I think now it's only a matter of bugfixing on your code. Question "Browsers' “back” button and the previous page's state" is answered.
Anyway, I assure you, I'm seeing your test page working on every browser, so maybe check on another pc, or your configuration.

Comment: I had tested it on the Firefox on another pc in my house, the Firefox of my friend who lives in another country, and Firefox from version 4 to version 20 via BrowserStack. And the pages don't work for them all. The title of this question has been changed.