# JavaScript disappears after using 'Back' / JavaScript postponing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've been working on some JavaScript for a little while, and one of the most frustrating things so far is that it seems my JavaScript is refusing to load if Back, Forward or Hard Refresh are used. Considering my website is built on static HTML pages generated repeatedly through a MySQL database connection, I had to manually add a moderator menu, but it seems to sometimes just refuse to appear?

```
if (getCookie('opt23') !== '1') {
    var ajaxtwo = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var wrap = '';
    if (document.getElementById("firstpage") !== null) {
        wrap = document.getElementById("firstpage");
    } else {
        wrap = document.getElementById("firstpageinside");
    }
    var main = document.createElement("div");
    main.setAttribute("id","modmenu");
    wrap.appendChild(main);
    ajaxtwo.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var reports = (ajaxtwo.responseText === '0' ? 'flagblue.png' : 'flag.png');
        reportcount.innerHTML = '<img src=' + ku_cgipath + '/css/images/mods/' + reports + ' style="height:15px;' +
                                'width:15px;" />' + ajaxtwo.responseText;
    };
    ajaxtwo.open("GET",ku_cgipath + "/manage_page.php?action=reports&count",true);
    ajaxtwo.send();
    var threadid = document.getElementsByName("replythread");

    // taking the initiative of togglePassword, this makes things less needlessly lengthy.
    main.innerHTML =
        '<h2>Quick Mod</h2>' +
        '<input type="hidden" name="threadid" value="' + threadid[0].value +'" />' +
        '<label for="modaction">Action </label><select id="action" name="modaction">' +
            '<option value="">&lt;none&gt;</option>' +
            '<option value="delpost">Delete posts</option>' +
            '<option value="rebuildone">Rebuild board</option>' +
            '<option value="bans">View Bans</option>' +
            '<option value="appeals">View Appeals</option>' +
            '<option value="stickypost">Sticky Thread</option>' +
            '<option value="unstickypost">Unsticky Thread</option>' +
            '<option value=lockpost>Lock Thread</option>' +
            '<option value="unlockpost">Unlock Thread</option>' +
            '<option value="bump">Instant Bump</option>' +
            '<option value="viewthread">Switch to Moderator View</option>' +
        '</select>' +
        '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">' +
        '<a href="' + ku_cgipath + '/manage_page.php?action=reports" target="_blank">' +
        '<span id="reportcount"></span></a> ';
    }
```

My second issue is in another JavaScript that I'm using to try to make these HTML pages function dynamically. I'm using AJAX to interact with a PHP script, however, when it brings back the page (basically taking the next page and straps it next to the first one with CSS, creating a 'duo view'), my JavaScript doesn't get applied, like time settings, or generated links. How does one deal with that? I can't use `window.onload` as it can only be used once - it's being used in another JavaScript. Do I just somehow modify the results of the PHP file as they come? I'm using a Regular Expression to grab the next page, so I can't actually modify the results inside the PHP... can I?

Willing to concede to most solutions, including rewrites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Answer to the First Question

This is a little JavaScript "*problem*" caused by the browser's Back-Forward cache! I've already answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15850567/238722), but for completeness, here's the solution:

Firefox and the iOS Safari are the only ones (as of this writing) *known* to have this issue. The solution is to hook into `window.unload` event, and a specific condition to reload the page inside `window.onpageshow`!

---

### **Firefox fix**

jQuery:

```js
$(window).unload(function () { $(window).unbind('unload'); });
```

JavaScript:

```js
function UnloadHandler() { window.removeEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false); }
window.addEventListener('unload', UnloadHandler, false);
```

### **iOS Safari fix**

jQuery:

```js
$(window).bind('pageshow', function(event) {
    if (event.originalEvent.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
});
```

JavaScript:

```js
window.addEventListener('pageshow', function (event) {
    if (event.persisted) {
        window.location.reload() 
    }
}, false);
```

---

## Answer to the Second Question

You *can* actually hook into the `onload` event with multiple scripts/multiple functions. Instead of using the overwriting form of hooking into an event, such as `ajaxtwo.onreadystatechange` - you should ["add" an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Simple example would be:

```js
ajaxtwo.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
    alert("hi! I'm done!");
}, false);
```

As for a helper function that will "do this for you" with backwards compatibility with some older versions of Internet Explorer; you can use this simple function:

```js
function AttachEventListener(element, event, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    } else if (element.attachEvent) {
        element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    } else {
        alert('Invalid element specified for AttachEventListener');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
AttachEventListener(ajaxtwo, 'readystatechange', function () {
    alert("hi! I'm using an awesome helper function!");
});
```