# How to hold textbox value after navigating to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a page(say sample page) which consists of four text boxes,and i given the value for all text box ,i have a button in the page for navigating, while clicking ,it will navigate to next page and in that page i have back button,while clicking back button it will come to the sample page but the value i given got cleared.

It will get clear in all browsers except IE 11 Browser.Is there any solution?

i am using asp.net text box and i am using jquery for to get value from text box.

how to prevent clearing text boxes after navigating to another page.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to keep the data in session.

Comment: May be IE 11 has cached whole page that why it ain't got cleared. You can preserve state of text-field either using session or cookie these are the only solution.

Comment: If i have 20 textboxes,for each how can i maintain cookie.is there any other solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `localStorage`:

```js
$(function() {
  var targetValue = localStorage.getItem('targetElVal');

  if (targetValue) { // if there is any value then set it.
    $('#targetEl').val(targetValue);
  }

  $('#targetEl').keydown(function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    if (e.which === 13) {
      localStorage.setItem('targetElVal', val); // set the value
    }
  });




});
```

Comment: Something like this: you could also use the url, by uri encoding your text and then adding it to the url params and on the new page read the url parameters, depending on what you need ofc. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

Comment: absolutely! but if you want not to show that in the url then at client one should use `Storage`.

Comment: It might be a good point to address the fact that when back button is used, script doesn't automatically runs again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791148/startup-javascript-code-is-not-executed-when-using-the-firefox-back-button

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the Textbox values as they were, you might want to look into State Management Techniques available in the .NET Framework.

You can try using Session or QueryStrings or even Cookies. Its your choice what you want to use.

Check this link : [State Management Overview from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

You need to assign the TextBox values to Sessions first and then retrieve those values from the Session and assign them back to the TextBox.

*Things might get tricky if you are talking about the browser back button here since its not possible to control its behavior from server side.* But if you are trying to move between postbacks then definitely using sessions or cookies can be of help here.

Here is an example of using a Session. On the page where your TextBoxes are, you can write this to store the TextBox value in a Session. This is to be written before you navigate onto some other page.

```
Session["someKey"] = yourTextBoxID.Text;
```

Now when you press back button and postback occurs, you can assign it back the value which was stored in Session like this :

```
yourTextBoxID.Text = Session["someKey"].ToString();
```

This is to be written outside of `!IsPostBack` and with a null check implemented.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unless a page refresh is forced, its very unlikely this will work as when using back button the cached version comes back.

Comment: A postback is needed here to make it work **this way**. If something like a browser back button is pressed, we might see something different happening or nothing happening at all.It will probably get the cached data at that time.

Comment: It is clearly stated in the question that the issue OP has happens when back buttons is used.

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be to have a unique ID, eg: User ID as the key and the value will be the JSON value of the textbox.

And then on window.beforeunload event, all the textbox values can be stored under the key

Eg: localStorage.setItem( 'unique_user_id_values' , JSON.stringify( [{ input1: 'foo' }, { input2: 'bar' }]) );

And these values can be retrieved using the JSON parse method.
JSON.parse(localStorage['unique_user_id_values-values'])