# Javascript not always working in WebView

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

I want to open a webpage in a WebView and click automatically on a button after the page has loaded. This is my current `WebView` class:

```
public class WebViewFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        openUrl();
    }

    private void openUrl() {
        setCookies();
        if (urlToOpen != null) {
            //tell webview to handle redirects (by default browser launches on redirects)
            webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

                    if (getActivity() != null)
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onShowLoading();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                    if (getActivity() != null) {
                        executeJS();
                        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).onHideLoading();
                    }
                }
            });
            if (javascriptToExecute != null) {
                webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            }
            webview.loadUrl(urlToOpen);
        }

    }

    private void executeJS() {
        System.out.println("executeJS(): " + javascriptToExecute);
        webview.loadUrl(javascriptToExecute);
    }    
}
```

I can use `"javascript:$('#customer-info-edit').click();"` or `"javascript:document.getElementById('customer-info-edit').click();"` both work fine.

But the problem is they work only one time. If I open the WebView for the first time, the button is clicked. However if I press physical back button and open the WebView again then the button is not clicked. Why isn't Javascript working every time?

Comment: In a browser the back button triggers a reload from the cache, which does not trigger a page load but rather reloads it in its previous state.  I've never used a webview so I can't say whether this is the same issue or not, but this link will give you some options to try.  Simply put the relevant script into your page directly... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791148/startup-javascript-code-is-not-executed-when-using-the-firefox-back-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem exactly was, but I found a working solution: add 500ms delay before executing javascript.