# Back button browser doesn't load javascript function on page

Tags: javascript

I created a function on javascript, here everything normal but as soon I got back to this page with the navigation back button on browser it does not enter to this function.
This happens usually on the 3rd forward and backwards NOT the first time I do it.
Here is my code but I don't think it's a code issue.

```
    let MyComponent = function (el) {
        this.el = el;
        this.init();
    };

MyComponent.prototype.init = function () {
    this.myComponentFunction();
};

MyComponent.prototype.myComponentFunction= function () {
    const myBtn = document.querySelector('.js-my-btn');
    const lMyBtn = this.el.querySelector('.js-l-btn');

    if (lMyBtn ) {
        lMyBtn.setAttribute('href', myBtn && myBtn.getAttribute('href'));
    }
}


window.addEventListener("load",function() {
        var myComponents = document.querySelectorAll('.my-component');
        [...myComponents].forEach(element => {
            new MyComponent(element)
        });
    });
```

This is my code on javascript and it doesn't enter on init() method.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: look into : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15791148/startup-javascript-code-is-not-executed-when-using-the-firefox-back-button

Comment: You could have probably fix this by avoiding using `load` event at all

Comment: it doesn't work, neither of your solutions.